# Query data doesn't update after successful apollo cache write

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo

I have a query on my App.js:

```
import { gql } from 'apollo-boost';

const ALL_ITEMS_QUERY = gql`
  query ALL_ITEMS_QUERY {
    challenges {
      id
      title
    }
    goals {
      id
      title
      completed
      createdAt
      updatedAt
      steps {
        id
        completed
        title
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

And i am looking to write a simple deleteGoal mutation:

```
const DeleteWrapper = (props) => {
  const [deleteGoal, { data }] = useMutation(DELETE_ITEM_MUTATION, {
    update(cache, payload) {
      const data = cache.readQuery({ query: ALL_ITEMS_QUERY });

      data.goals = data.goals.filter(
        (goal) => goal.id !== payload.data.deleteGoal.id
      );

      cache.writeQuery({ query: ALL_ITEMS_QUERY, data });
    },
  });
}
```

The function returns the modified array correctly, but the item never disappears from the frontend list. I have a hunch that this is related to querying multiple categories at once (goals and challenges, rather than goals only).

Even though the cache seems to be modified correclty, why does the item never disappear, why does the re-render never happen?

Comment: `ziele` not used in query ?

Comment: You could upgrade to Apollo Client 3.0 (which is recommended by Apollo) and use cache.evict(ziel_to_delete.id);

Comment: @xadm Fixed, I used placeholders. Everything is being used as it should.

Comment: @Spray'n'Pray Upgrading to a Beta is not exactly what I had intended. Since everything functions without errors now, what's to say that the new version won't also just ignore the cache change?

Comment: query usage? - what needs to be updated? how rendered? etc.

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error I found out that I have to lay out the exact `data` object to the `writeQuery` function. I don't really understand why, since the challenges object was left untouched after the query. I have not been able to make this work otherwise.

```
const DeleteWrapper = (props) => {
  const [deleteGoal] = useMutation(DELETE_ITEM_MUTATION, {
    update(cache, { data: { deleteGoal} }) {
      const { goals, challenges } = cache.readQuery({ query: ALL_ITEMS_QUERY });

      const newArr = goals.filter((goal) => goal.id !== deleteGoal.id);

      cache.writeQuery({
        query: ALL_ITEMS_QUERY,
        data: { challenges, goals: newArr },
      });

    },
  });
}
```

Comment: the same object mutated - not change detected ... but you don't need spread challanges if not changed.... `data: { challenges, goals: newArr }` - creates entire new object using existing challenges and new goals

Comment: @xadm Edited, Cheers